# Spring kafka infinite retries without retryabletopic annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are using spring Kafka 3.x and using DefaultErrorHandler.
In this handler, we check if the exception is retriable then do retries till Integer.maxValue else put a message in DLT.
Whole idea is to do infinite retries for certain exceptions and DLT for few.
For infinite retries, we have used exponential back off.
At some point, exponential back off will exceed the max poll timeout.
I want to understand how it is going to behave when it exceeds the max poll interval.

As per my understanding, this is a stateful retry as STCEH is deprecated in spring Kafka 3.x"

Can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the exponential back off never exceeds the `max.poll.interval.ms`; otherwise a rebalance will be forced.

This was true, even with the old stateful retry mechanism; before that was added, the aggregate of the delays could not exceed the interval.

Now (with either mechanism), only the max delay must be less than the interval.